# Keep getting CAPTCHA every time playwright (trying to scrape Capterra reviews)

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

I've been trying to scrape reviews from Capterra and the code itself works fine but I have a problem where every time I launch a browser using playwright and go to Capterra website I get a Captcha (Press and Hold one).

I've tried a lot of ways to get around it. I tried playwright's `stealth_sync()` but it didn't help. I use rotating residential proxy and now use different `user-agents`, locales, timezone's, change the `viewport` and even tried to go to Capterra from Google but I'm not able to escape this CAPTCHA.

Here is my code:

```
# Functions to avoid the CAPTCHA.

def emulate_human_like_behavior(page):
    # Mimic mouse movements and interactions
    page.mouse.move(100, 100)
    page.mouse.down()
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 1))
    page.mouse.move(200, 200)
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 1))
    page.mouse.up()

def get_random_user_agent():
    with open('Test/browser_settings/user_agent.txt', 'r') as file:
        user_agents = file.readlines()

    # Remove leading and trailing whitespace, and choose a random user agent
    random_user_agent = random.choice(user_agents).strip()
    return random_user_agent

def get_random_locale():
    with open('Test/browser_settings/locale.txt', 'r') as file:
        locale = file.readlines()

    # Remove leading and trailing whitespace, and choose a random locale
    random_locale = random.choice(locale).strip()
    return random_locale

def get_random_timezone_id():
    with open('Test/browser_settings/timezone_id.txt', 'r') as file:
        timezone_id = file.readlines()

    # Remove leading and trailing whitespace, and choose a random timezone_id
    random_timezone_id = random.choice(timezone_id).strip()
    return random_timezone_id

def get_random_viewport_size():
    # Define a range for random width and height
    min_width = 800
    max_width = 1600
    min_height = 600
    max_height = 1200    
    # Generate random width and height while maintaining aspect ratio
    width = random.randint(min_width, max_width)
    height = width * (max_height - min_height) // (max_width - min_width)
    return width, height


def scrape_capterra_reviews(url, limit, start):
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=False, proxy={"server": "SOMETHING",
                                                      "username": "SOMETHING",
                                                      "password": "SOMETHING"
                                                      })
    width, height = get_random_viewport_size()
    context = browser.new_context(user_agent = get_random_user_agent(),
                                  viewport={"width": width, "height": height},
                                  screen= {"width": width, "height": height},
                                  is_mobile=False,
                                  locale=get_random_locale(),
                                  timezone_id=get_random_timezone_id()
                                  )
    page1 = context.new_page()
    #stealth_sync(page1)

    #===Building up cookies
    page1.goto("https://www.google.com/")
    #check_for_cookie_agreement(page1)
    try:
        if page1.query_selector('xpath=/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/form[2]/input[14]').is_visible():
            page1.query_selector('xpath=/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/form[2]/input[14]').click()
    except:
        pass

    #Input bar
    try:
        if page1.query_selector('xpath=/html/body/div/c-wiz/div/div/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/button').is_visible():
            page1.query_selector('xpath=/html/body/div/c-wiz/div/div/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/button').click()
    except:
        pass
    try:
        page1.fill('xpath=/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/input', 'Capterra')
        page1.press('xpath=/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/input', "Enter")
    except:
        pass
    try:
        page1.fill('xpath=//*[@id="mib"]', 'Capterra')
        page1.press('xpath=//*[@id="mib"]', "Enter")
    except:
        pass
    try:
        page1.fill('xpath=/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/input', 'Capterra')
        page1.press('xpath=/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/input', "Enter")
    except:
        pass
        
        
        
    time.sleep(random.uniform(1.5, 3))

    try:
        if page1.query_selector('xpath=/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/form[2]/input[14]').is_visible():
            page1.query_selector('xpath=/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/form[2]/input[14]').click()
    except:
        pass

    time.sleep(random.uniform(1.5, 3))
    emulate_human_like_behavior(page1)
    time.sleep(random.uniform(1.5, 3))
    page1.query_selector('xpath=/html/body/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/a/div/div[1]/h3/div').click()
    
    page1.goto(url, timeout=600000)
    reviews = []

    page1.wait_for_selector('.gtm-review-section', timeout=60000)
    review_element = page1.query_selector('.gtm-review-section [data-test-id="review-card"]')
    review_author_name = review_element.query_selector('.nb-flex').query_selector('.nb-flex').text_content()
    rating_elements_raw = page1.locator(f'//*[@id="LoadableReviewSection"]/div/div[3]/div[{1}]/div/div/div[1]/strong/div/div/div[6]')
    rating_elements = rating_elements_raw.text_content()
    print("Author: ", review_author_name)
    print("Rating: ", rating_elements)

    context.close()
    browser.close()

    return reviews
```

All these scary try - excepts you see was just a way for me to type Capterra in Google search and then go to their website to avoid direct links but no results with it either.

Also I tried testing my bot on this website https://bot.sannysoft.com/ but most of the fields (if not all of them) were green and no major red flags for giving me CAPTCHA.

Does anyone have any  suggestions on what can help in this situation because I'm quickly running out of options and hope.

Comment: Sort of an aside, but those ultra-rigid xpaths are not reliable. See [Playwright docs](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/locators#locate-by-css-or-xpath): "CSS and XPath are not recommended as the DOM can often change leading to non resilient tests.".

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for letting me know! I'll try to avoid using it as much as possible.

Comment: Curious, were you ever able to solve your question? what worked in the end?